# Rank starts and ends of events in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Say that I have a table that looks like this:

```
person  | date                  | action
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00.0 | Start
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00.5 | SomeRandomAmountOfStuffBetween
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:01.0 | End
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:02.0 | ThingWithoutStartOrEnd
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:03.0 | Start
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:03.5 | SomeRandomAmountOfStuffBetween
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:03.7 | SomeRandomAmountOfStuffBetween
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:04.0 | End
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:05.0 | ThingWithoutStartOrEnd
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:06.0 | Start
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:07.0 | End
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:08.0 | ThingWithoutStartOrEnd
```

I want all the starts and ends to be ranked. I can do something like:

```sql
sum(case when action = 'End' then 1 end)
           over (partition by person order by date desc
               rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

Which basically counts the amount of ends before itself, which is mostly ok. However, the things in between that don't have a start or end also get a rank, how do I make those rows be excluded from rank if I don't know the actual value of "ThingWithoutStartOrEnd"? The output should look like this:

```
person  | date                  | action                         | rnk
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00.0 | Start                          | 1
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00.5 | SomeRandomAmountOfStuffBetween | 1
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:01.0 | End                            | 1
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:02.0 | ThingWithoutStartOrEnd         | NULL
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:03.0 | Start                          | 2
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:03.5 | SomeRandomAmountOfStuffBetween | 2
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:03.7 | SomeRandomAmountOfStuffBetween | 2
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:04.0 | End                            | 2
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:05.0 | ThingWithoutStartOrEnd         | NULL
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:06.0 | Start                          | 3
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:07.0 | End                            | 3
person1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:08.0 | ThingWithoutStartOrEnd         | NULL
```

What am I missing to exclude these records from the rank?

Answer (score 0):

Count both start and end:

```
(case when sum(case when action = 'Start' then 1
                    when action = 'End' then -1
                    else 0
               end) over (partition by person
                          order by date
                          rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                         ) > 0 or
           action = 'End'
      then sum(case when action = 'End' then 1
               end) over (partition by person
                          order by date desc
                          rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                         ) 
 end)
```